# What happened to Old New York?

Tags: futurama

In my previous question, '[Why is the Cryogenics Lab in New New York?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19687/why-is-the-cryogenics-lab-in-new-new-york)' we discussed why the Cryogenics Lab was in New New York when it was originally in Old New York. Old New York was Destroyed by Bender but later in the episode it was shown to be in the sewers of New New York.

Was Old New York Destroyed or built over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the very 1st episode, they showed that there were parts of Old New York that was just built over.  Not as in bulldozed, but as in they created a platform in where they can build their new city.  Most parts of old New York is still intact, some was buried and build over, and other was just replaced.

As for the Cryogenics Lab, engineers could have moved the chambers to a new location.  Cryo-chambers don't defrost automatically when disconnected, as you see in "Cryogenic Woman".

Comment: Even in the New York of today, if you go down deep enough, you'll find parts of Old New York

Answer (score 0):

It was destroyed (not completely) and built over. I think it was the episode where Farnsworth, Fry and Bender were in the time machine and you can see the Earth go through phases of growth and destruction. They thought it was the end of time but ended up watching the big bang and eventually you see Old New York being built and destroyed by aliens and Bender!

That part where you see Bender in Old New York is a reference to *[Bender's Big Score](http://theinfosphere.org/Bender%27s_Big_Score)* in which Bender uses the time code to go back in time.